# how to rollback the database changes after perform few actions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I have Rails application and I run the test cases, but my database is very huge When I run the test cases then I perform some create/update/delete so I want to rollback all operation after run the test case.

#### Currently what I am doing:

I have back-up file then after each test cases I import the whole database. but It takes around 30 minutes and I need some better solution.

Comment: How do you run those manipulations?

Comment: @emaillenin I mean create/update/delete of models, when run the test cases

Comment: if you write tests correctly it should not be a problem, because all tests are wrapped in transaction and changes are rollback automatically. Show your `spec_helper.rb` and some tests where you have problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use gem database_cleaner

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @self I don't think user1546240 could write a comment because of low reputation level.